# Line separator in command line

Tags: linux, command-line

How do I send an email, where "Hello world!" appears in the first line and "Test run" appears in the second line. I have tried \r\n and \n. Are there any way to stack the line after line?

```
echo "Hello world! \r\n Test run" | mail -s "Test" abc@abctest.com
```

The email should be viewed like:

Hello world!

Test run

Comment: `echo $'foo\nbar'` works in bash, at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more than two or three lines, you can also use the following syntax:

```
mail -s "Test" abc@abctest.com << EOF
```

then type your mail and finally a line with only `EOF` in it; it will allow you to type text on several lines as a single "logical" command line. (Try to browse the history of your command line after that, you will understand what I mean by "one logical command line".

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo -e`. From the manual:

> If the -e  option
>                 is  given,  interpretation  of the following backslash-escaped characters is enabled. [...]

```
# echo -e "Hello world! \r\n Test run"
Hello world!
 Test run
```

In bash you can also use `$'string'`:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands
>   to string,  with  backslash-escaped  characters  replaced  as  specified by the ANSI C standard.

```
# echo $'Hello world! \r\n Test run'
Hello world!
 Test run
```